# Image in Lyx from text snippet

Tags: graphics, lyx, conversion

I use a utility which creates EPS images from short text snippets. To use this utility with Lyx I see two approaches:

1. Put the text snippet in a file, define a file converter in Lyx and include it as an image (the way I currently do it).
2. Use inline TeX to create the image from the text snippet (I really don't know how to do this but I assume it's possible).

With the first approach I get to see the resulting image in Lyx, but I have to edit an external file to make changes (and having to keep track of all those files). With the second approach I can edit the text snippets directly in Lyx, but I need to preview the document to see the result.

The question: Is there some way I can both edit the text snippets **and** see the resulting graphics directly in Lyx? It would be ideal if I could just click on the image to bring up a text entry to edit the corresponding text snippet.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Why exactly do you want the text as an image, and not as regular text? Can you provide an example or a screenshot of a use case?

Comment: Maybe creating an "external template" could be what you want. It can do preview. Read the Customization manual (Help > Customization) and look at existing external templates as examples.

Comment: @Marijn I described the problem in this generic way since I have had more than one use case. One of them is typesetting hieroglyphs (which must be done semi-manually with one of the two scripts designed for the purpose). The other is harder to describe, but then the image is not text at all but rather a kind of graph.

Comment: @scottkosty External templates seems to provide the same kind of solution as defining an image converter, if I need to choose an external file to use. If there isn't a way to insert the "content" of the file instead? (So I can edit the "content" in LyX instead of having to keep track of external files.)

Comment: @Fabel ah I see. Well, at least in LyX you should be able to right-click and go to "edit externally". When you save and exit the external program, LyX should automatically update the preview. Other than that, the only idea I can think of could be something like pLyX: https://wiki.lyx.org/Examples/PLyXSystem